# Pandas groupby month and year (date as datetime64[ns]) and summarized by count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have a data frame, which I created in pandas, grouping by date and summarizing by rides.

```
      date   rides
0   2019-01-01  247279
1   2019-01-02  585996
2   2019-01-03  660631
3   2019-01-04  662011
4   2019-01-05  440848
..         ...     ...
451 2020-03-27  218499
452 2020-03-28  143305
453 2020-03-29  110833
454 2020-03-30  207743
455 2020-03-31  199623

[456 rows x 2 columns]
```

My `date` column is in `datetime64[ns]`.

```
date     datetime64[ns]
rides             int64
dtype: object
```

Now I would like to create another data frame, grouping by month and year (I have data form 2019 and 2020) and summarize by rides.

Ideal output:

```
Year Month   Rides
2019 January 2000000
2020 March   1000000
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can `groupby` and get the [dt.year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and the [dt.month_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html) from the column date.

```
print (df.groupby([df['date'].dt.year.rename('year'), 
                   df['date'].dt.month_name().rename('month')])
         ['rides'].sum().reset_index())
   year    month    rides
0  2019  January  2596765
1  2020    March   880003
```

Comment: Perfecto! The King! Thank you so much!

Comment: I will accept your answer because you were the first :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

`datetime` also support the `to_period` conversion, so we can group everything by a Monthly period.

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period('M')).agg('sum')
#           rides
#date            
#2019-01  2596765
#2020-03   880003
```

In this case the index is a `PeriodIndex`, which has many of the same `datetime` attributes.

```
PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2020-03'], dtype='period[M]', name='date', freq='M')
```

Comment: @Ben.T it's nice if you need a flexible function to allow for different aggregations. For instance it's very easy to change the above to aggregate to Year, Y-Quarter, Y-M groups, (literally change to Y, Q, M) as opposed to calling all the attributes. Basically it's `resample`, but doesn't given you all of the `NaN` groups in between.

Comment: Maybe add strftime ?